# Converting echop to date and time

Tags: input

import datetime
import time

started_at = 1622847663941
print(started_at)

stDt = int(started_at) /1000 / 86400 + 25569

sD = datetime.strptime(stDt,"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")

print(sD)

Comment: I am getting below error1622847663941
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-9e6226792347> in <module>()
      7 stDt = int(started_at) /1000 / 86400 + 25569
      8 
----> 9 sD = datetime.strptime(stDt,"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
     10 
     11 print(sD)

AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'strptime'

Comment: please read title as epoch